# Cuál sería la manera mas óptima de crear las tablas en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que consiste en ver el proceso de empaquetado de los productos, mi pregunta es como son varios productos de diferentes categorías o tipos, están los de tipo syrup (toda medicina para la tos), cremas, píldoras, cápsulas y pastillas, que sería lo más óptimo?, registrar todos los productos en una misma tabla con su nombre, cantidad y tipo y a la hora de hacer la consulta hacer select * from productos where tipo = al tipo que el usuario necesite o registrar cada producto en su respectiva tabla dependiendo de su tipo y hacer el select en la tabla de los productos del tipo que seleccione el usuario?, para mi sería la segunda opción ya que con la primera si tienes 1mil productos registrados y le dices que te los devuelva dependiendo de su tipo este tiene que recorrer sin embargo con el segundo ya te devuelve todos, espero haberme explicado bien :)

Answer (score 1):

Para decidir la disgregación de una tabla entre varias según el valor de un atributo hay que tener en cuenta cuantos valores nulos nos ahorra la nueva estructura.

Si los distintos tipos de productos no son más que eso, el valor que identifica el tipo, pero no tiene más consecuencias, es conveniente poner todos los productos en la misma tabla. Si para ciertos tipos hay que registrar valores adicionales, entonces conviene la disgregación para evitar los nulos que supondrían esos atributos específicos para los productos de otros tipos.

Muchos tiene que haber para que se note el incremento de tiempo en un select. Si efectivamente estamos hablando de decenas de miles de productos, y la consulta por tipo es frecuente, entonces vale la pena añadir un índice en esa columna, de forma que NO DEBERÁ RECORRER TODA LA TABLA para hacer el select, sino que lo hará en un tiempo proporcional al número de cifras de la cantidad de productos que haya, es decir, en log(n), ya que para eso sirve la indexación.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Estaba empezando a responder hablando de modelado, de entidades y atributos... y la verdad es que esta forma de justificarlo es muchísimo más clara, ahí te va mi (+1). Gracias por la aportación

Comment: gracias a ti, David.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, escogería una sola tabla para los productos, ya que si un tipo de producto sale del modelo de negocio la tabla sería obsoleta. Si el tipo de producto esta representado mediante un numero realmente el tiempo de la consulta sera muy bajo, no llegará a notarse hasta que sea una cantidad realmente enorme de registros y aún entonces, me parece mas que justificado dada la simplicidad que se aportaría al diseño, reduciendo los costos de mantenimiento de la base de datos y aumentando su mantenibilidad y escalabilidad. Ahora que si un producto se diferencia radicalmente de los otros tipos y es fundamental para el negocio si valdría la pena hacer otra tabla independiente.